# jQuery working fine in console but on site doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A am trying to disable a text input based on whether or not a checkbox is checked. After writing the required jQuery and trying it in console the result is perfect. However, when adding it to the sites footer the page loads as if the jQuery hasn't be executed.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').attr('checked', false)
  jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

  jQuery('form input[name="custom_checkbox"]').click(function() {

    if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == true) {

      jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", false);

    } else if (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false) {

      jQuery('form input[name="company"]').prop("disabled", true);

    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <input type="checkbox" name="custom_checkbox">
  <input type="text" name="company">
</form>
```

Ideally I would like to have the checkbox unchecked and the text field disabled upon page load. Then if the user checks the box the text field will be enabled.

When the page loads at the moment:

1. The checkbox is unchecked + the text field is enabled
2. If I check the box the field remains enabled
3. If I then uncheck the box the field becomes enabled

So after clicking the intended functionality happens but on load the default are wrong.

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you at least checked the console for errors?

Comment: In the snippet it works fine for me

Comment: I have converted your code to snippet and it works (see if you can reproduce the issue)

Comment: Your code seems to work so not sure what the issue is. It can be cleaned up to be less code.

Comment: if you put one console.log('test'); in before the "document.ready" and one in the callback of "document.ready", are they both visible in console?

Comment: And where is your JS defined? In an external sheet which is loaded after jquery or in the  html itself? Make sure it is defined a the very bottom of your page, just before the closing body tag.

Comment: Check the console for errors. if jquery isn't included when your script runs it will probably write an error like "jQuery is undefined"

Comment: it might be silly, but have you tried to clean your cache?